Why can't the icon for the Chrome extension I developed be displayed?
I am developing a Chrome extension that is displayed in the Developer Tools, similar to Network. I used the chrome.devtools.panels.create method and passed the iconPath parameter, but it didn't work. Why?
manifest.json
{
  "manifest_version":3,
  "name": "fengjianxiong",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "A custom DevTools panel.",
  "permissions": [
    "storage","webRequest","debugger"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "*://*/*"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "devtools_page": "devtools.html",
  "icons": {
    "16": "16.png",
    "32": "32.png",
    "48": "48.png",
    "128": "128.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": [
        "content.js"
      ],
      "matches": [
       "<all_urls>"
      ]
    }
  ]
}


enter image description here
enter image description here
I tried replacing the iconPath parameter in the chrome.devtools.panels.create method with images of different sizes, but none of them were displayed. I want the image to be shown on the tab

Devtools stopped showing icons for all panels. Apparently, it's an intentional design decision.
